# Proof by induction for $2^{n+1} < 1 + (n+1)\times 2^n$ for $n \geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

I have to prove the predicate in the title. I've did the cases for $P(1)$ and assumed that it is true for all $P(k)$. I am stuck at the step for the predicate $P(k+1)$:

$2^{k+2} < 1 + (k+2)\times 2^{k+1}$

Comment: If you assume that it is true for all $P(k)$, then you are assuming the very thinh that you want to prove.

Comment: That is the induction hypothesis or am I incorrect?

Comment: You are incorrect. The induction hypothesis consists in assuming that what you want to prove holds for **some** $P(k)$, not for **every** $P(k)$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason why you want to prove it by induction? It seems much more natural to prove it directly: since $n\geq 1$, we have $1+(n+1)2^n\geq 1+(1+1)2^n=1+2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank for the response. I'm currently studying this particular section proof techniques (induction) and came across the question. I've attempted it, but was not successful in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

The case for $n=1$ is trivial. Now, suppose it's true for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, that's to say, our induction hypothesis is 
$$2^n(n+1)+1> 2^{n+1}.$$
Then, let's prove that it's true for $n+1$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2^{n+1}(n+2)+1 &=2^{n+1}(n+1)+2^{n+1}+1 \\
& = 2\cdot 2^n(n+1) +2^{n+1}+2-1 \\
& = 2(2^n(n+1)+1) +2^{n+1}-1 \\
& > 2\cdot 2^{n+1} +2^{n+1}-1 \quad \text{(induction hypothesis)} \\
& = 2^{n+2} +(2^{n+1}-1) \\
& > 2^{n+2} \quad \text{(because } 2^{n+1}>1 \text{ for all } n\in \mathbb{N})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the inequation as

$$0<1+(n-1)2^n$$

and it feels hard to... not think it true.

If you cannot live without induction,

$$0<1+(n-1)2^n<1+n2^{n+1}$$ because the terms in the RHS are no smaller.